# Scope within for loop

Tags: javascript

I've been starting to use IIFEs within for-loops, like so:

```
var currentItem = 2; // IIFE helps prevent variable collision
for(var i = 0; myArray.length < i; i++){
    (function(){
        var currentItem = myArray[i];
        // do stuff
    })();
}
```

The main reason I've been doing this is to give some scope to the for-loop, so the variables don't escape this scope. Are there any negative effects/performance hits of doing so? And if so, what is the extent of their harm? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use `.forEach()`?

Comment: @Pointy - IE8 support and curiosity.

Comment: There is a "performance hit": creating and invoking an anonymous function is not free. Btw, what is the real reason to do so? Variables (like `currentItem` and `i`) are visible after the loop, so what?

Comment: Care to explain exactly what kind of hit you're speaking of?

Comment: There's no advantage to doing that because you aren't capturing any variables inside the function. You're reaching to the wider scope that the for loop exists in for `i`.

Comment: @FillipPeyton — Functions require memory and processing.

Comment: But `currentItem` isn't reaching the outer scope, and that is my goal.

Also, I understand that functions require memory and processing. I guess my follow up questions are: How large of an effect does this have on a program? And is it enough of an effect to rationalize not using the IIFE?

Comment: Depends on what the `// do stuff` is whether the IIFE is necessary or just superflouous (and harmful to performance).

Comment: @FillipPeyton: If you don't feel any effects on your program, then it's not enough to care. You can measure performance of your application with both approaches if you're interested.

Comment: Good idea. I was just more curious if this was a serious concern or not. I can create some tests.

Comment: @FillipPeyton it should be the opposite - what is the **real problem** you're solving with this approach? "I don't like variables having wider scope than they might" is not a problem.

Comment: The value of `currentItem` already exists in the outer scope because it exists in `myArray`. Assigning it to a new variable neither gains nor costs memory (except a negligible amount in a lookup table somewhere)—the value exists only once in memory.

Comment: @Jordan "nor costs memory" --- that's not true. The standard does not require implementations to optimise assigning a scalar values (which might be a 100Mb long string).

Comment: @zerkms - First thing that comes to mind is variable collision. I'm sure I can think of other issues that this would help with too.

Comment: @FillipPeyton please demonstrate the exact "collision" (I cannot think of how one could have one honestly)

Comment: Okay, I'll give you that, @zerkms, but do you really think any browser in common use is dumb enough to needlessly copy that value?

Comment: @Jordan for primitive numbers - that's what they do. It's tiny, but it's performed.

Comment: @zerkms Fair enough. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: How about `for (...) doStuff(myArray[i]);` where `function doStuff(currentItem) { // do stuff }`. Overall, the answer is: it depends (on the engine).

Comment: Consider moving the loop inside the IIFE. This way there will only be one function creation and one call, instead of one at each iteration.

Comment: @FillipPeyton IE8 support is a pretty terrible reason; there are widely available, perfectly serviceable polyfills for `.forEach()`.

Comment: I would say that it isn't a terrible reason. I have my reasons for needing this, so the reasoning is subjective to each developer/situation.
And besides all of that, my question still stands the way I asked it. Yet another ailment of SO: I'm tired of getting answers like "why don't you just change your requirements"?

Comment: @FillipPeyton You haven't really explained your requirements, so the best we can do is guess, based on your question, that they are artificial or based on wrong assumptions. If you have your reasons, then tell us what they are if you expect a good answer. I presume you're familiar with what an X-Y problem is? As I imagine you know, performance can be very subjective and inconsistent, so asking a question solely about performance without stating up front any of your reasons for wanting to do this as opposed a more orthodox approach makes this a bad question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a performance cost in wrapping the body of a `for` statement into an anonymous function. The problem is the cost of creating a new function object for each iteration. That is, for each iteration a new function object is created with its own scope.

[Performance comparison named vs anonymous function](http://jsperf.com/named-or-anonymous-functions/12)
This is a small comparison between named function and function declaration which may help you to understand the impact over the performance of your code. Note, in your case, the problem is not the anonymous function, but rather the cost of creating the function object.

---

**ES6**

I understand, you are trying to scope your variable to the `for`. I would suggest another solution to achieve this. If you can, try to use [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) keyword from ES6.

The `let` keyword has been introduced to overcome all of `var`'s defects, such as this one. `let` allows you to declares variable that are limited in scope to the `for` block.

[From the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let):

> `let` allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the
>   block, statement, or expression on which it is used. This is unlike
>   the var keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an
>   entire function regardless of block scope.

Comment: Thank you for providing an actual answer instead of a comment. This is actually helpful :)

Comment: You don't invoke an anonymous function in the first case, so you compare different things.

Comment: `let` sounds pretty great! Can't wait to see it pick up more traction as far as browser support goes!